# Best way to parse/find text with Python

Tags: string, parsing, python-2.7, find, split

I have a file that I've read into memory and I would like to parse or search that particular string for all occurrences of "TEST_COMMAND".  I could have commands like TEST_COMMAND.1, TEST_COMMAND.2, etc.  I simply want to find all of these occurances of TEST_COMMAND and then split on the period (.) so I can get the data on the right of the period.  For example, TEST_COMMAND.1 and TEST_COMMAND.2 would result in adding 1, 2 to the list.

I've been messing around with str.find and parse but can't seem to put anything together that will work.  If any of you have some ideas I would love to hear them.

Here is some updated data.  Need to parse a file with the following:

function TEST_CMD.OFF(uuid, uprm)
function TEST_CMD.NUMBER_1(uuid, uprm)

Basically I would need to parse this file take whatever is aafter the . but before the (uuid, urpm).  In this case I would like the output to be ['OFF', 'NUMBER_1']

Comment: [regex](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
In [8]: s
Out[8]: 'some string, TEST_COMMAND.1, some other string, TEST_COMMAND.2'

In [9]: import re

In [10]: re.findall(r'TEST_COMMAND\.(\d+)', s)
Out[10]: ['1', '2']
```

**Update**

Try

```
In [20]: re.findall(r'TEST_CMD\.([^(]+)', ss)
Out[20]: ['OFF', 'NUMBER_1']
```

for your second question

Comment: Thanks for the example.  It works well when using a hard coded string like the example above.  However, when I feed it the actual string that was loaded from a file I don't get the needed results.  For example, if I strip the .(\d+) off then I get the results of ['TEST_COMMAND','TEST_COMMAND'] but when I add the .(\d+) back on I get an empty list returned [].  Perhaps that is related to the following:

    function TEST_COMMAND.1(uuid, uprm)

Comment: Here is an example of my output if I take off the .(\d+)

[u'TEST_COMMAND.', u'TEST_COMMAND.'

Comment: Looks like I needed to do the .(\D+) that will matches any character which is not a Unicode decimal digit.

Comment: I do have another question on it if you look at the updated data I posted in the question.